# Interface Index to Name in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, linux-device-driver, ifconfig

I have an index for the network interface I got a packet from, and need to find the name of interface. e.g. myFuntion(2) returns "eth0". Can someone help with an example if how to do it in C++ on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/if_indextoname ? Are we talking user- or kernel space?

Comment: Can you help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108811/cannot-convert-char-to-char