# cannot convert ‘char**’ to ‘char*’

Tags: c++, ifconfig

I have an index for the network interface I got a packet from (i.e. 2), and need to find the name of interface, which should return `"eth0"`. I'm using [`if_indextoname()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/if_indextoname).

I'm not much familiar with C++ on Ubuntu, but my code drops an error:

> cannot convert `char**` to `char*` for argument 2 to `char* if_indextoname(unsigned int, char*)`

Can someone help me to fix it?

```
#include <net/if.h>
#include <iostream>    

int main()
{
    unsigned int ifindex = 2;
    char *ifname[10];
    std::cout << if_indextoname(ifindex, ifname);
    std::cout << ifname << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You're passing an array of `char *` to something that expects a `char *`. Maybe you meant `char ifname[IF_NAMESIZE];` (or a higher size, or use the buffer of a `std::string` of that size in C++11).

Comment: It has nothing to do with Linux or Ubuntu. It is just C++. An array of `char*` cannot decay to a `char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *ifname[10];` declares 10 char pointers.

I guess what you need is a char pointer.
`char* ifname = new char[IF_NAMESIZE+1]` should solve your problem.

Alternatively, you could just allocate an auto char buffer, if you do not want to pass it to other functions.

`char ifname[IF_NAMESIZE+1]`

Comment: Simply doing `char ifn[IF_NAMESIZE + 1] = "";` using `auto` allocation seems more appropriate.

Comment: Sure, added that as well.

Comment: Thank you. And I just looked up `IF_NAMESIZE`, and it is indeed `#define`ed in `/usr/include/net/if.h`.